# How to access a private file in aws s3 in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-s3

how to access a private file in aws.s3 in angularjs using the api KEY and SECRET

i have the login api key and secret , the file is private ,
i need to display the file in my browser using angularjs

when i try  it gives

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>8645A4E13B8C1FA5</RequestId>
<HostId>
0EnuTRDbQ38bVSYORlj8qdpNXxC38LMmsv8n0aMEgiE1LxKImuHKejnSFHtyaBQqEXj9guXOUww=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Id":"http referer policy example",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":"s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{"aws:Referer":["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

or

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Id":"PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
   "Statement":[
     {
       "Sid":" Grant a CloudFront Origin Identity access to support private content",
       "Effect":"Allow",
       "Principal":{"CanonicalUser":"79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be"},
       "Action":"s3:GetObject",
       "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"
     }
   ]
}
```

change bucket policy